# How to change spacing between radio button and its text?

Tags: html, css

I have the following HTML:

```html
<input type="radio" name="beds" value="1" />1+
<input type="radio" name="beds" value="2" />2+
```

How do I change the spacing between the radio button and the "1+" text? I'd like the text to be **closer** to the radio button, but the browser is inserting a certain amount of undefined padding between the two elements.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Many HTML elements have a default margin setting. You can override this and set it to 0. In your case, you want to reset `margin-right` on the radio button:

```
<input type="radio" name="beds" value="1" style="margin-right: 0" />1+
```

You probably want to add it to your stylesheet so that it applies to all radio buttons:

```
input[type="radio"] {
  margin-right: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 19):

You'll need the `label` element.

```
<input type="radio" name="beds" value="1" id="first" /><label for="first">1+</label>
<input type="radio" name="beds" value="2" id="second" /><label for="second">2+</label>
```

You can then style this like this:

```
label {
  margin-left: -3px;
}
```

Also note the use of the `for` attribute for accessibility purposes.

Answer (score 1):

Just change the input id's width to auto in css.

```
#input-id {
width: auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add this to your stylesheet:

```
input[type="radio"] {  
  margin-right: 10px;
}
```

Comment: And what would happen next, why would that help?

Comment: it creates spacing of 10px between radio button and text

Answer (score 0):

First Create id's inside input tag (eg `id="input1"`), then style id's in css file(eg `#input1{margin-left:5px; margin-top:5px;}`) also you can use inline styling using `margin-top:5px`,and `margin-left:5px`

[image: img]

Comment: Please read [answer]. Among other things https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. 
Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. [link-only-answers](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/link-only-answers/info)

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="radio" name="beds" value="1" id="first" />
<label for="first">
1+
</label>
<input type="radio" name="beds" value="2" id="second" />
<label for="second">
2+
</label>
```

this is what you have

change your +1 (and +2) to

<h:outputText value ="+1" style="margin-left: -3px"/>

You have to mess with the style of the text you are using as a label, and to do that you need it to be an actual element, not just raw text.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).