# How to give space between radio button and radio button text

Tags: css, struts2

Here is my radio button code in struts tag, the space between radio button and radio button text box is congested how to give space between them

```
  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-lg-3 control-label">Gender</label>
    <div class="col-lg-5">
    <div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">
    <s:radio name="studentDTO.s_gender" id="gender" list="{'Male','Female'}" />
    </div>                              
    </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: you should use CSS for this task, see http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_margin.asp

Comment: This question does not appear to be about programming within the scope defined in the help center.

Answer (score 2):

Many HTML elements have a default margin setting. You can override this and set it to 0. In your case, you want to reset margin-right on the radio button:

```html
   <input type="radio" name="beds" value="1" style="margin-right: 0" />1+
```

You probably want to add it to your stylesheet so that it applies to all radio buttons:

```html
input[type="radio"] {
  margin-right: 0;
}
```

Comment: i need to give space @Rebecca

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3655265/css-how-to-change-spacing-between-radio-button-and-its-text

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31317716/how-to-add-space-between-text-and-radio-button

Comment: check above links

Comment: change CSS for struts tag simply

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old question but to do this in Struts 2 use the `cssStyle` attribute if you only want it to apply to this group of radio buttons.

```
<s:radio name="studentDTO.s_gender" id="gender" list="{'Male','Female'}" cssStyle="margin-right:20px" />
```

Or you can use the `cssClass` attribute.

```
<s:radio name="studentDTO.s_gender" id="gender" list="{'Male','Female'}" cssClass="radioMarginRight" />
```

with

```
.radioMarginRight{
margin-right: 20px !important;
}
```

Both of these apply the `CSS` to the radio button and the label.  To keep the margin from applying to the label with the `cssClass` attribute you could define the following `CSS` to set the label margin to 0.

```
label.radioMarginRight{
margin-right: 0px !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I dont know struts, but looking at this have you tried:

> list="{' Male ',' Female '}"

Just putting some spaces between each of the '.

Its what you do in HTML + CSS so might work there